# Internal hom: products and coproducts

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, enriched-category-theory

It seems to me that

> Assuming the all smalllimits and colimits exist:
>   Internal hom for a closed symmetric monoidal category satisfies: 
>   $$[\bigsqcup C_i, X] \cong \prod_i [C_i, X] $$ 
>   where $(-)\otimes X: V \rightarrow V $, have right adjoint $[X,-]:V \rightarrow V$.

My proof is by showing that they represent the same object in $V$. Is this isomorphism true?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Oh, I was asking whether this is correct. Sorry.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, if you don't mind, I would be grateful if you could give a look at my question on 5.4.1.1 luries HTT. I am still confused how is there an induced map.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should show us your proof, but the standard proof carries out essentially like the proof that left adjoints preserve colimits and right adjoints preserve limits. $[\_, X]$ actually turns all colimits into limits, not just coproducts into products ($[\_, X]: V^{op} \to V$ preserves limits).

For objects $X$ and $Y$ in $V$ and a diagram $F: J \to V$,

$$
\begin{aligned}
C(X, [ \mathrm{colim}_{j \in J} F(j), Y ] ) & \simeq C(X \otimes \mathrm{colim}_{j \in J} F(j), Y ) \\
& \simeq C(\mathrm{colim}_{j \in J} F(j) \otimes X, Y ) \\
& \simeq C(\mathrm{colim}_{j \in J} F(j), [X, Y] ) \\
& \simeq \lim_{j \in J} C(F(j), [X, Y] ) \\
& \simeq \lim_{j \in J} C(F(j) \otimes X, Y ) \\
& \simeq \lim_{j \in J} C(X \otimes F(j), Y ) \\
& \simeq \lim_{j \in J} C(X, [F(j), Y] ) \\
& \simeq C(X, \lim_{j \in J} [F(j), Y] ) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Since this is natural in $X$, $[ \mathrm{colim}_{j \in J} F(j), Y ] \simeq \lim_{j \in J} [F(j), Y]$ by the Yoneda lemma.